# Using Yarn's registry error: Service RegistryOperations is in wrong state: INITED

Tags: java, hadoop, cloud, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to write a Yarn application master that submits itself into Yarn's registry (Hadoop 2.6)

In essence this is what the application master is trying to do:

```
ApplicationId id = ...
String path = ...

YarnConfiguration conf = new YarnConfiguration();    
RegistryOperations registryOperations = RegistryOperationsFactory.createInstance(conf);

ServiceRecord record = new ServiceRecord();
record.set(YarnRegistryAttributes.YARN_ID, applicationId);
record.set(YarnRegistryAttributes.YARN_PERSISTENCE,PersistencePolicies.APPLICATION_ATTEMPT);

registryOperations.bind(path, record, BindFlags.CREATE | BindFlags.OVERWRITE);
```

When submitting this code to hadoop 2.6 I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: Service RegistryOperations is in wrong state: INITED
at org.apache.hadoop.registry.client.impl.zk.CuratorService.checkServiceLive(CuratorService.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.registry.client.impl.zk.CuratorService.zkSet(CuratorService.java:633)
at org.apache.hadoop.registry.client.impl.zk.RegistryOperationsService.bind(RegistryOperationsService.java:114)
...
```

Googling the problem yield no usable results, so I tried inspecting the relevant Yarn's source code - currently without success

Anyone else having this problem? any Idea's of what causing it or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the `RegistryOperationsFactory` javadoc it said that calling any of the `create*` functions will initialize the resulted `RegistryOperations` instance. 
What I didnt know is that while `RegistryOperationsFactory` initialize it, It still need to get started.. so this code works:

```
ApplicationId id = ...
String path = ...

YarnConfiguration conf = new YarnConfiguration();    
RegistryOperations registryOperations = RegistryOperationsFactory.createInstance(conf);
registryOperations.start();

ServiceRecord record = new ServiceRecord();
record.set(YarnRegistryAttributes.YARN_ID, applicationId);
record.set(YarnRegistryAttributes.YARN_PERSISTENCE,PersistencePolicies.APPLICATION_ATTEMPT);

registryOperations.bind(path, record, BindFlags.CREATE | BindFlags.OVERWRITE);
```